# MCSession delegate methods are not firing when i send the media

Tags: ios11, multipeer-connectivity

I am doing one application using Multipeer connectivity.In that when i send the media files from one iOS to another iOS device using sendResourceURL method, destination device receiving correctly.But when i try to send from iOS 11 device to below versions, MCsession one of the delegate method is not firing

```
- (void)  session:(MCSession *)session
didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName
     fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
        atURL:(NSURL *)localURL
    withError:(nullable NSError *)error
{

 }
```

At some point this method is not firing, but media file saved to temporary location.I found this using the delegate method

```
- (void)                    session:(MCSession *)session
didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName
                       fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
                   withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress
{
}
```

So can you please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: have you found the problem? I am facing the same issue. I think that it could be related to this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/262655#262655